# All combinations of 4 out of 7 columns with totals using excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have 7 columns to choose from and I need to pick 4 of those columns and generate a total for each row. I also need every combination of 4, which means I'll have 35 new columns with the totals for each of those combinations showing in each row. I need the code for this and if it can be done only using Excel. Here is an image of the columns and the grayed ones are the 7 columns I'm talking about. My knowledge of Excel is very limited. There are over 1,500 rows if that matters.

[image: Excel image of my problem]

Comment: Have you tried researching on your concern? What have you tried so far that didn't work? Please do share.

Comment: I spent about a week searching on the internet to my problem, which I don't think I explained very well now that I look at it. I don't think Excel alone can do what I need. I tried COMBINE, but that only told me that there are 35 combinations of 4 out of 7 with no repeats. So I think I'm going to just figure out all 35 combinations and make 35 columns with, example =SUM(AB,AD,AF,AH) etc. so I can drag the square down from that to get all 1,500 row totals for that combination. I don't think Excel alone can achieve that. I was just trying to find a quicker way.

Answer (score 1):

multi step approach that is going to use some helper rows.  there may be a more elegant formula that will do this, and much slicker options in VBA, but this is a formula only approach.

#### Step 1 - Generate List of Column Combination

To generate the list 4 helper rows will need to be insert at the top of your data.  either above or below you header row.  These 4 rows will represent the column number you are going to pick.  To keep the math simpler for me I just assumed the 1 for the first column and 7 for the last column.  those numbers will get converted to later to account for column in between in your spreadsheet.  For the sake of this example The first combination sum will occur in column AO and the first helper row will be row 1.  The first combination will be hard coded and it will seed the pattern for the remainder of column combinations.  Enter the following values in the corresponding cells:

```
AO1 = 1
AO2 = 2
AO3 = 3
AO4 = 4
```

In the adjacent column a formula will be placed and copied to the right.  It will automatically augment the bottom value by 1 until it hits its maximum value at which point the value in the row above will increase by 1 and the the value of the current will be 1 more than the cell above.  This will produce a pattern that covers all 35 combinations by the time column BW is reached.  Place the formulas below in the appropriate cell and copy to the right:

```
AP1
=IF(AO2=5,AO1+1,AO1)

AP2
=IF(AO2=5,AP1+1,IF(AO3=6,AO2+1,AO2))

AP3
=IF(AO3=6,AP2+1,IF(AO4=7,AO3+1,AO3))

AP4
=IF(AO4=7,AP3+1,AO4+1)
```

#### Step2 - Sum The Appropriate Columns

I was hoping to use a some sort of array type operation to read through the column reference numbers above, but I could not get my head around it.  Since it was just 4 entries to worry about I simply added each reference manually in a `SUM` function.  Now the important thing to note is that we will be using the `INDEX` function over the 13 columns that cover the range of your columns  so to convert the index number we figured out above, to something that will work to grab every second row, the number that was calculated will be multiplied by 2 and then 1 will be subtracted.  That means 1,2,3,4 for the first column combination becomes 1,3,5,7.  You can see this in the following formula.  Place the following formula in the appropriate cell and copy down and to the right as needed.

```
AO5
=INDEX($AB5:$AN5,AO$1*2-1)+INDEX($AB5:$AN5,AO$2*2-1)+INDEX($AB5:$AN5,AO$3*2-1)+INDEX($AB5:$AN5,AO$4*2-1)
```

pay careful attention to the $ which will lock row or column reference and prevent them from changing as the formula is copied.

Now you may need to adjust the cell references to match your sheet.

[image: proof of concept]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think due to my poor explanation and the fact that I don't Excel alone can achieve what I want. I'm just going to create all 35 combinations for each of the 35 columns, example =SUM(AB,AD,AF,AH) etc., so I can just drag that first box down to get all the totals for all 1,500 rows of that combination.